# Getting an Element from Array Property,.I am getting the right Answer so why won't it accept?

Tags: javascript

```
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
 

  for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj[i].length === 0 || !Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
      return undefined;
    }

    
     for(var y = 0; y < obj[i].length; y++) {

      if(!obj[key][index]) {
         return undefined;
       }

      if(obj[i][y] === obj[key][index]) {
         return obj[key][index];
      }

       
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
 key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey']
};
var output = getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 0);
console.log(output); // --> 'Jamil'
```

Here are the criteria for this problem -

X) should return the element at the index of the array at the key of the passed in object

```
✓ should return undefined if the index is out of range
✓ should return undefined if the property at the key is not an array
✓ should return undefined if there is no property at the key
```

I am returning 'Jamil' as requested, so why does it not like my output? Is there something I'm conceptually not getting here? Or is the exercise bugged?

Comment: Why are you looping through all the keys in the object? The problem with your function is that it will return a value based purely on the first key it looks at, regardless of what the `key` argument actually is.

Comment: Why you aren't doing that `return obj[i][index]` instead of the second loop?

Comment: What do you mean "why does it not like my output" ? Is this a test environment?

Comment: @arminyahya no this is a coding homework problem I've been stuck on for awhile

Comment: if(obj[i][y] === obj[i][index]) {
         return obj[i][index];
      }

still gets the same answer but it doesn't like the code. Maybe the problem is bugged?

Comment: We need to see their Arbitration system. Maybe its a bug

Comment: @Brixsta can you share the link to the exercise?

Comment: @MajedBadawi sadly I can't it's a coding class I'm in. I'm going to bring this up with the instructors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. If `obj` doesn't have the `key`, or `obj[key]` is not an `array`, or the `index` is invalid => return `undefined`
2. Else the arguments are valid, hence, return `obj[key][index]`

```js
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  if(!obj[key] || !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || index < 0 || index >= obj[key].length)
    return undefined;
  return obj[key][index];
}

const obj = { key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey'], key1: 'str' };
console.log( 'obj, key, 0 => ',  getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 0) );
console.log( 'obj, key, 2 => ',  getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 2) );
console.log( 'obj, key, -1 => ', getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', -1) );
console.log( 'obj, key1, 0 => ', getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key1', 0) );
console.log( 'obj, key2, 0 => ', getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key2', 0) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.find` on the entries of the object

```js
function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
  const maybeFoundIt = Object.entries(obj)
    .find(([xkey, value]) => xkey === key &&
      Array.isArray(value) &&
      value.length &&
      +index > -1 &&
      index < value.length);
  // return the value if something was found, otherwise undefined    
  return maybeFoundIt ? maybeFoundIt[1][index] : undefined;
}

const obj = {
  key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey'],
  notArray: {
    x: 1
  },
};

const yepNope = isOk => isOk ? "✓" : "X";
console.log(`should return undefined if the index is out of range: ${
    yepNope(!getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 24))}`);
console.log(`**should return undefined if no index is given: ${
    yepNope(!getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key'))}`);
console.log(`should return undefined if the property at the key is not an array: ${
    yepNope(!getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'notArray', 0))}`);
console.log(`should return undefined if there is no property at the key: ${
    yepNope(!getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'dontknowthis', 0))}`);
console.log(`otherwise returns a value: ${
    yepNope(getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, 'key', 0))}`);
```